# Notice: Undefined index: that doesn't seem to be solved

Tags: php, pdo

I'm kinda new to php and since I started using it I encounter this error `Notice: Undefined index: title_1`
I connected the table

```
$ind_header = $db->query("SELECT * FROM header_index")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I try `<?php echo $ind_header['title_1']; ?>` I get that error, but when I use a `foreach` loop it works.
Now I wanna show the results of the database in a form value like this

```
<form action="<?php echo BASE_URL ?>/admin/admin.php" method="POST">
    <label>Title one</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title_1" placeholder="Full name" value="<?php echo $ind_header['title_1']; ?>">
```

I get this full error

> Notice: Undefined index: title_1 in D:\wamp\www\translate\app\views\cms\body_views\header.php on line 11 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0010132416{main}( )..\admin.php:0 20.0060141696require( 'D:\wamp\www\translate\app\views\admin\admin.php' )..\admin.php:4 30.0070145864include( 'D:\wamp\www\translate\app\views\cms\body.php' )..\admin.php:3 40.0070149056include( 'D:\wamp\www\translate\app\views\cms\body_views\header.php' )..\body.php:7 ">

Comment: `->fetchAll()` returns **all** rows in a multidimentional array, so that is why a  foreach loop allows you to access `title_1`. If you only want the 1st value, either change the `->fetchAll()` to `->fetch()` **OR** you can do `$ind_header[0]['title_1']` where `[0]` represents the row you want the `title_1` value from

Comment: @Sean Now it worked, thank you for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchAll()` returns all data in multidimensional array. To get data you need to use

```
$ind_header[0]['title_1']
```

When you use `foreach()` it is automatically handled by system.